# WordPress - Sum meta value by post_parent

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to run a WPDB query for counting value of post meta:

```
Sum meta Value by post_id which have post_parent = xx
```

I have a WPDB code but I dont know how to get by post_parent:

```
$wpdb->get_results("SELECT SUM($wpdb->postmeta.meta_value) 
      FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE `post_id` = get_the_ID()");
```

Comment: Can you tell me more detail about post_parent because post is non-hierarchy.

Answer (score -1):

```
$wpdb->get_results("SELECT SUM( wp_postmeta.meta_value )
FROM wp_postmeta
WHERE wp_postmeta.post_id =".get_the_ID());
```